# Is it possible to compare two arrays in a nested loop for three conditions?

Tags: arrays, language-agnostic, comparison

Say you have two arrays (pseudo-code):

```
arrayA = [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ];
arrayB = [ "b", "c", "d", "e" ];
```

Is it possible to find `unique items to arrayA` (arrayA.a), `common items` (b, c, d), and `unique items to arrayB` (arrayB.e) using only two loops in a nested format?

We can determine the first two objectives as such:

```
// Loop over arrayA
for (itemA in arrayA) {

    // Loop over arrayB
    for (itemB in arrayB) {

        // Assume that arrayA.itemA does not exist in arrayB by default
        exists = false;

        // Check for matching arrayA.itemA in arrayB
        if (itemA == itemB) {

            // If true set exists variable and break the loop
            exists = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Tells us if an item is common
    if (exists) {
        // Do something
    }

    // The additional condition we need to determine (item is unique to array b)
    else if () {}

    // Tells us if the item is unique to arrayA
    else {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

**Question:** Can we go a step further and determine the third condition (an item is unique to arrayB)? The trick is to be able to act on the third condition in the iteration of the first loop.

The loops can be in any format (do while, do, for, for in) and in any combination.

Comment: Hash tables would make quick work of this problem - heck, even a single "seen" bit for the items in arrayB would do the trick! So what operations are you allowed to do in the loops except array accesses and built-in operators? None?

Comment: @Kilian, sorry, I omitted something. You need to be able to act on the condition in the iteration of the first loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second condition (item is unique to array b) will always be false, since you are iterating through items in A at that point.   However, to answer your first question of building the 3 arrays with 2 loops in a nested format, here's what I would do:

```
//Set up the arrays to hold the values
uniqueA = itemA;//copy of item A
uniqueB = itemB;//copy of item B
common = [];

//Iterate through the arrays to populate the values
for (itemA in arrayA) {
    for (itemB in arrayB) {
        if(itemB == itemA){
            comon.add(itemA);
            uniqueA.remove(itemA);
            uniqueB.remove(itemB);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note** You could argue that copying `itemA` and `itemB` is iterating through them.  The only way I see around this is if you don't care about keeping the initial array values and the values are unique, in which case you can use `arrayA` and `arrayB` in place of `uniqueA` and `uniqueB` respectively.

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this by removing the common elements from ArrayB when they are detected. That way ArrayB will only contain its unqiue elements.

This will also increase efficiency in further checks. Note that the algorithm will need to be amended if ArrayA contains duplicate items.

```
if (itemA == itemB) {

             // If true set exists variable and break the loop
             exists = true;
arrayB.remove(ItemB);
             break;
          }
```

Comment: sorry, see my updated question! You need to be able to act on the condition within the first loop iteration

Comment: @Mohamad In that case it seems that what you are trying to do is flawed. Which element in ArrayB would you attempt to access in the loop for ArrayA? You first need to check over ALL elements in ArrayA in order to determine what elements are common in ArrayB and therefore which are unique. I would say it is not possible but please open my mind and prove me wrong.

Comment: perhaps I inadvertently abused the "tag" puzzle here. I actually don't know if this is possible. This is why I asked. I'll retag the question.

Comment: @Mohamad With the conditions you are imposing I do not think it is possible. It seems trivial to attempt to do it this way, is there are real issue here that you are trying to overcome or is this simply a game?

Comment: it's not a game. Although I know it's easy overcome the issue by using an additional loop over the remainder of items in arrayB (like your example). I was just curious to see if there was a way to do it in two loops using a any combination of loop-types. I was mashing it in my head for a while, and I couldn't find a way. I wanted to see if it was possible and others knew of a way. Should probably close this question then.